# How i can do Rollback insert and Delete statements executed

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Hi I have lot of delete statements followed by lot of insert statements.
How i can do rollback of all statements in case of any failure happening during any statement execution .
Ex : i have 10 delete statements and followed by 10 insert  statements . If my last insert statement failed i need to roll back all delete and insert statements happend . Which would be the easiest way to achieve this ?

Comment: are doing this actions (delete, insert) directly in DB or from Java or Spring?

Comment: If you have the delete and insert logic inside a single method, just add @Transactional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. Putting Spring's @Transactional annotation on top of your method inside which you are performing the inserts/deletes
2. Manually creating and managing the transaction

First way is recommended.

Examples:

Using purely Spring:

```
@Service
public class MyPersistenceService {

  @Autowired
  private MyRepository mytRepository;

  @Transactional
  public void myLogic() {
     //perform all the inserts and deletes
  }

}
```

Using Hibernate with Spring:

```
@Component
public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {


 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;

 @Override
 @Transactional
 public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
   Book book = new Book();
   book.setId(1L);
   book.setAuthor("author");
   book.setTitle("title");
   entityManager.merge(book); //an insert statement

   entityManager.remove(book); //a delete statement
 }
}
```

Second way is a very crud way to do this , since you are already using Spring. Here is a code snippet to do that:

```
Session session = null;  
Transaction tx = null;  
  
try {  
  session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
  tx = session.beginTransaction();  
  //Your insert and delete statements 
  
  tx.commit();  
  
}catch (Exception ex) {  
  ex.printStackTrace();  
  tx.rollback();  
}  
finally {
  session.close();
}
```